# Stability of eigenvectors from symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be symmetric matricies. Denote with $\lambda_i$ the eigenvalues of $A$ and with $\lambda_i'$ the eigenvalues of $B$. Then it is known by the Hoffman and Wielandt Theorem that we find a permutation $\sigma$ with
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n | \lambda_i - \lambda_{\sigma(i)}'| \leq ||A - B ||$$
where $|| \cdot ||$ denotes the Frobenius Norm.

I also found in [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/when-are-eigenvalues-stable/) article from Terry Tao that if $A$ is normal (in particular symmetric) then the eigenvalues are very stable under small perturbations.

My question is, can something similar be stated for the corresponding eigenvectors for symmetric matricies?

Comment: You might be interested in [Weyl's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for the reference, it is very interesting. However, I am really curious about the eigenvectors. - Whoops! Just noticed that I didnt mention this in my question - I edited it.

Answer (score 4):

The question you raise is on the *perturbation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of symmetric matrices*. There is an excellent presentation of this in  *Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators*, by Tosio Kato, and in particular, in Chapter 1. (Springer Verlag 1980).

The answer to you question is positive, for symmetric matrices with distinct eigenvalues - if $A(\lambda)$, depends analytically on $\lambda$, then so do the eigenvectors (suitably defined), provided that they are distinct.